# TO_TIMESTAMP query behaves different for same datatype columns Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have a view that I'm querying against, this view is pulling the data from 3 different tables. The curious thing is that when I execute this query:

```
    select * from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD where FISCAL_MONTH_START_DT =
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

it works as expected.. it returns all of the rows with a date like `2016-01-01`

But when I execute a query of the same type against another column:

```
    select * from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD where VOYAGE_STRT_DT = 
TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-07 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

it returns no rows.. even if there are many dates with the value '2014-04-07'
The columns are from different tables and of type 'Date'. I can only use `TO_TIMESTAMP()`  and not `TO_DATE()`. Any ideas of where do I need to look to solve this?

Comment: "I can only use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` and not `TO_DATE()`"? Seriously? Why? I haven't heard this one before.

Comment: @mathguy  everyday we heard new things don't we? It's because this query is generated by Dynamic Linq in C# and there is no way to manipulate the IQueryable generated to use TO_DATE()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all your `FISCAL_MONTH_START_DT` values are at midnight (which seems reasonable from the column name) but your `VOYAGE_STRT_DT` are not - they have other times of day, so they aren't matching your query, which is only looking for exactly midnight.

```
select * from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD
where VOYAGE_STRT_DT >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-07 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
and VOYAGE_STRT_DT < TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-08 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

or more simply:

```
select * from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD
where VOYAGE_STRT_DT >= TIMESTAMP '2014-04-07 00:00:00'
and VOYAGE_STRT_DT < TIMESTAMP '2014-04-08 00:00:00'
```

or even more simply:

```
select * from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD
where VOYAGE_STRT_DT >= DATE '2014-04-07'
and VOYAGE_STRT_DT < DATE '2014-04-08'
```

though if you can't use `to_date()` for some reason (!?) you may not be able to use date or timestamp literals either.

---

You may be seeing just the date part when you query the table in other ways, which is down to your client and NLS settings. To check the times you can change your settings or explicitly format the values:

```
select to_char(VOYAGE_STRT_DT, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as VOYAGE_STRT_DT
from CPOB_MONITORING_DASHBOARD
where VOYAGE_STRT_DT >= DATE '2014-04-07'
and VOYAGE_STRT_DT < DATE '2014-04-08'
```

Comment: great catch! This should work, I'm going to test it later and select your response if works!

Comment: You were right! I changed NLS settings to display time too and `FISCAL_MONTH_START_DT` time is set midnight, while `VOYAGE_STRT_DT` is set to 9:00!